# Rubyで勝手にprivate method扱いされる

Tags: ruby

とある問題を解くために以下のようなコードをかきました。
しかし、gravityメソッドが勝手にprivate扱いされてしまいます。
'#'の付いている行をすべてコメントアウトすると期待通りに動きました。
どなたか詳しい方、なぜgravityがprivate扱いされてしまうのか教えてください
処理系は2.3.1です。

---

```
line = gets.chomp.split(' ')
$W = line[0].to_i
$H = line[1].to_i
$N = line[2].to_i
$sen = Array.new
$H.times do
　　　$sen << gets.chomp.split("")
end
$sen.reverse!
$sen = $sen.transpose

def gravity #落ちる
　　　$sen.each do |y|
　　　　　　y.delete('0')
　　　　　　($H-y.length).times do
　　　　　　　　　y << '0'
　　　　　　end
　　　end
end #
$sen.gravity #
p $sen
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。やっとミスとその原因がわかりました

Answer (score 4, accepted):

このコードの本質的な問題は`gravity`メソッドの呼び出し方が不適切なことです。本来は`undefined method`になるほうが好ましいように思えるのですが、後述するRubyの動作により、プライベートメソッドの呼び出しのエラーになってしまいます。

単純な解決策としては`$sen.gravity`ではなく、`gravity`として呼び出してください。

また、メソッド定義じゃなくしたら動作した、とありますが、このコードだとメソッド定義する必要がないので、それも一つの解決策だと思います。

---

マニュアルには確かに「トップレベルで定義したメソッドは main オブジェクトの private メソッドと して定義されます。」と書いてあるのですが、質問のコードの挙動とは矛盾しているので説明になってません。

マニュアルの通りであれば、`gravity`は`main`オブジェクトのメソッドなのですから、`$sen.gravity`は`undefined method`になるはずです。ところが実際には`private method 'gravity' called`のエラーになります。

実際には、トップレベルで定義したメソッドはKernelモジュールのプライベートなインスタンスメソッドとして定義されます。KernelモジュールはObjectクラスがincludeしておりObjectクラスは全てのクラスのスーパークラスなので、トップレベルで定義したメソッドは全てのクラスにおいてプライベートなインスタンスメソッドとして参照できることになります。

```
def m
  p self.class
end

[].__send(:m) #=> Array
{}.__send(:m) #=> Hash
#無理矢理呼び出す

def hoge
  puts "hoge"
end

class Hoge
  def fuga
    hoge
  end 
end

Hoge.new.fuga #=> "hogeを表示"
Hoge.new.hoge #=> private method `hoge' called for #<Hoge:0x00000804ce1f10> (NoMethodError)
```

---

Answer (score 2):

「なぜgravityがprivate扱いされてしまうのか教えてください」という質問については、Ruby公式マニュアルに[「トップレベルで定義したメソッドはmainオブジェクトのprivateメソッドとして定義されます。」](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/class/main.html)と書かれています。